# How do I make a system where a random dog wins each time?

Tags: c#, random, instance

So let's say I had a class called dogs and another called People. I  need those people to be able to bet on the dogs and they do so by number ( So "people" bets on dog number 2 ). 
If the dog wins they get cash money otherwise they lose it. 
Now the problem I have is making the system where each dog wins everytime. 
I thought about doing this:

```
class Dog
    {
        public Random random;
        private bool race()
        {
            for (int i = random.Next(1,10); i < 10; i++)
            {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
    }
```

That would make it generate a random number between 1 and 4 for each instance that called the race method. But with that, eventually ALL of them will get to 10 and return true as I have no way of saying " When one of the instances returns true, stop all the other instances's methods.
And also, if by coincidence two instances generate the same number then they will both win and I don't want to have two winners either. So how could I improve this method or make a better one where I can make as many instances as I want of dog but only one dog would win?

Keep in mind i'm really new to this and can't use events yet.

Comment: You should not implement the logic for the game in the entity dog. Place it in a class called something like arena, and this class knows the dogs and can calculate who will win

Comment: But then I'm still at the problem where i'm not sure how to get only one dog to win.

Comment: Your arena knows all dogs, which are in the arena. and you algorithm for the winner choose one dog out of the collection of dogs. so you have only one dog which will win the game

Comment: @Francesco Now i'm just a noob atm at this but are you sure? Isn't it suppost to keep cycling untill it reaches 10 or more? The 1,10 is just the initial number but I'm pretty sure that aslong as it isn't 10 or more it will keep adding 1 to I because of the "I++"                         Also, what do you mean i'm missing random initializatino?

Comment: Yes, what's happening here is that the first value of i is something between 1 and 9 (included), which is < 10. This means that it enter the for loop where the only instruction is return false. This causes your method to exit immediately with a result of false without ever reaching i++. Regarding initialization, you are missing random = new Random(); and your code would generate a null reference exception (i.e. it would try to have null executing the Next method)

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way to deal with that would be to create a `Race` class or similar.

```
public class Race
{
    public Dog Race(Dog[] dogs)
    {
        Random random = new Random();
        return dogs[random.Next(0, dogs.Length)];
    }
}
```

Comment: As I said i'm really new and am not at the stage where I use var yet.   Also, is there possibly a way where I can do it in a method?               And would it help if I knew I was going to use only 4 dogs and won't need more instances than 4?

Comment: Sorry, `var` is just a replacement for `Random`, I changed the code so that you don't have to bother. It doesn't help to know there are 4 dogs, and check Tomtom's comment, he explains why you can't just use a method.